# No way to solve as.Date returning NA

Tags: r, na, as.date

R Studio beginner here. I am trying to turn a character into a date through as.Date.
My code is like this:

> date=c("23-Nov-1994")
>
> date <- as.Date(date, format="%Y%m%d")

but it returns NA.

I also tried

> as.POSIXlt("23-11-1994", format="%d-%m-%Y")

which returns [1] NA

The locale shouldn't be the issue:

> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")

returns [1] "English_United States.1252"

Finally, I tried to use lubridate as someone suggested in another thread but R returns that there is no package called lubridate!
I really don't understand why, can anyone help? R version is 3.4.4.

Thank you!

Comment: read `?strptime` very carefully. then read it again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format should match the order, `%m` is for numeric months

```
as.Date(date, format="%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "1994-11-23"
```

---

Also, this can be done with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(date)
#[1] "1994-11-23"
```

Or with `anytime`

```
anytime::anydate(date)
#[1] "1994-11-23"
```

Comment: To expand slightly: the `format` argument defines the format of the input data. So `"23-Nov-1994"` is in the format `%d-%b-%Y`. The `as.Date` function reads this and then knows how to deal with the data.

Comment: I totally missed that the format is about the input format and not the desired output format and this was driving me crazy. Thank you.